# Is using CROSS JOIN here a bad idea?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm creating this table:

```
    ID|Name|Company
    1 |Foo |Acme Corp
    2 |Bar |Acme Corp
    3 |Doh |Acme Corp
```

from:

```
    ID|Name
    1 |Foo 
    2 |Bar 
    3 |Doh
```

and:

```
    ID|Company   | Address 
    1 |Acme Corp | Bugs Bunny Lane
```

Is it a bad idea to CROSS JOIN the record from second table to the first table?

I'm importing data from multiple databases(representing multiple companies) into a new one. The second table in each database is only supposed to have one record ever. What's an alternate way of doing this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If I were you I would have created a view, it would prevent from having the same data in different tables, but who knows, you might be creating an ETL procedure. As @Mureinik asked you, what goal do you want to achieve?

Comment: I am indeed creating an ETL procedure..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need all combinations and you tables are not logically linked, `CROSS JOIN` is exactly how you do that:

```
SELECT  stuff.*, company.name
FROM    stuff
CROSS JOIN
        company
```

Comment: I think OP wants to create a new table because he doesn't want to have to do a cross join.

Comment: @ForguesR: sure but I believe he's asking how to populate this table in the first place (i. e. how to write a query to append `INSERT` to)?

Comment: My downvote is because the question is _is it a bad idea to CROSS JOIN the record from second table to the first table?_.  OP is not asking how to to do a cross join.  I don't think merging the two table is a good idea.

Comment: @ForguesR: you thinking that merging the tables is a bad idea or using a `CROSS JOIN` to do this as requested is a bad idea? If the former, it's the wrong post to downvote; if the latter, could you please explain why?

Comment: In your answer explain why it is a good idea to merge (denormalize) the two tables and you'll get my vote.

Comment: @ForguesR: I'm not the OP, I'm just answering the questions. A valid reason would be, say, to speed up the queries.

Answer (score 0):

If by *cross join* you mean creating the new table `(ID|Name|Company)` then it is probably a bad idea.

You have a single company for now but you never know in the future.  You will also lose the address and maybe other information (phone number?) unless you repeat that information on every line.

I'd stick with two tables!